# If a baddie is using, are they abusing?

Tags: differences, semantics

The following sentence got me thinking [1](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/2002/12/elqorchi.htm):

> While hawala is used for the legitimate transfer of funds, its
> anonymity and minimal documentation have also made it vulnerable to
> abuse by individuals and groups transferring funds to finance illegal
> activities.

The context makes it clear that those "individuals and groups" are actually using the system exactly as it is supposed to. Their goals are bad, but they don't target the system itself. Is it correct to call this abuse? Do I *abuse* a shoe to kick a puppy?

Edit:

I looked up the word [2](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=281158c9dd148079&q=abuse&si=AKbGX_oRjcCPa5QPMQwD2ABTMArQGpveaifgbdBDJ25SwGD0Dndv6E-FrSlMZo-iGnMcvot6rj9mJ4Uf2V5o3FG8lLSLrP57vA%3D%3D&expnd=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTlcfx_oyEAxXOEVkFHQWRBJgQ2v4IegUIFRC-Ag&biw=1744&bih=836&dpr=1.1), and the most relevant answer was

> use (something) to bad effect or for a bad purpose; misuse.
> "the judge abused his power by imposing the fines"

The judge in the example seems to be doing something *wrong*, or at least excessive. Is this use applicable to the "individuals and groups transferring funds" above, who use the system correctly, or is this, ahem, *abuse*?

Edit 2:

Some context the quote above is missing: hawala is informal system and may not have explicit terms of service.

Comment: A situation can be vulnerable to abuse. Abuse is not just of people.  You can abuse a system. Please go and look up the word.

Comment: Have you tried looking up "abuse" in a dictionary?

Comment: "A baddie is using" sounds like a drug addict.

Comment: @Lambie Excellent suggestion, I edited the question.

Comment: Do you really think "financ[ing] illegal activities" is allowed by the terms of such services?

Comment: @Laurel: Seems like hawala is often informal and might not have terms like this explicitly laid out

Comment: Terms of use are rarely read and so fly under most people's radar, so there's scant reason *not* to forbid financing illegal activities, by way of warding off liability in case someone gets caught--even if you have intentionally designed and built your app or platform to serve the market for illegal/immoral transactions. But in that case, is it still *abuse* to employ the thing in the manner thus intended by its maker? Or should the test be rather the mere possibility of unexceptionable use? (In the case of a firearm, that might be firing at or threatening an armed home invader.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal purpose of a financial system is to facilitate payment for legitimate purchases. Using it to facilitate money laundering or other illegal activities is generally considered abuse. We can similarly say that using a social media platform for bullying or spreading disinformation is abuse -- they're not the kinds of legitimate communication that the platforms were created for.

So it doesn't matter *who* is using it, what matters is what they're using it for. A "baddie" can make legitimate purchases using hawala,  and that's not abuse. But when they use it for their illegal activities, that's abuse.

Your example of the shoe is difficult to categorize. Just because you happen to be wearing a shoe when you're kicking the puppy, we don't usually consider you to be *using* the shoe. And if you're not using something, you're not **ab**using it, either.

We could, however, say that you're abusing your foot by using it to kick the puppy. However, this is likely to be confused with the definition of "abuse" that means to cause damage to a part of your body, so we wouldn't normally say this.

The definition you quoted is also missing some nuance. It's not just that the effect is bad, it should also not be the intended use. Guns are made for killing, so shooting someone is not abusing the gun.

Comment: The OP is wondering why 'abuse a thing for bad ends' works with the thing = 'the system', but does not sound right if the thing = 'the shoe'. Are you abusing a shoe if you 'put to wrong or improper use'?  Can you elaborate in your answer?

Comment: That seems more of a philosophical question than a language question. When you kick something, you don't really consider that you're "using" the shoe at all, it just happens to be on your foot when you do it.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to better reflect what the OP was asking.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. Deleting comments